# display unique values from MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the `isbn` number of a book from a database, but with my command it is giving me an associative array.

How do I get it to return just the `isbn` number in the array.

Code:

```
function view_all_names($db)
{
$query = "SELECT  isbn from books";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
return $result;      

}
```

Comment: Your query returns only isbn numbers.

Comment: What is `$db` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$db` is a PDO object you can use

```
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

[PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 0):

you should take only isbn numbers use mysql_fetch_assoc() with while loop.